# mysql treat a column field as null if it is blank

Tags: java, mysql

Hi this is the table I am querying:

```
mytable
id, name
1,name1
2,name2
3,' ' //this is a white space
4,null
```

but when i use this query to set blank columns to null:

```
update mytable set `name`= CASE `name` WHEN '' THEN NULL ELSE `name` END;
```

It updates even the column field which has space in it.
so the result is :

```
1,name1
2,name2
3,null
4,null
```

Why does mysql treat whitespace also as '' blank?
Is there any option to replace only blanks in the table to null and let the whitespaces be whitespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because MySQL treats `''`, `' '` or even `'       '` as the same.

Try querying:

```
select '' = '             '
```

It will return 1 that means true. So, MySQL treats all the whitespace strings of any length as equals.

If you want to update the rows with 0 length empty string, use `Length` function:

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET 
    `name` = NULL
WHERE
    `name` = '' AND LENGTH(`name`) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

nullif( trim(name) , '') is NULL

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif

try this..:)

Comment: I've never seen a use-case for `NULLIF()` before today. Huh.